# Specifying Command Line Parameters in C via BASH

Tags: c, bash, unix, command-line

I have compiled a C program in BASH which requires command line arguments. However, for the life of me, I can't remember how to specify them at launch. Such a trivial question.

For example I am running the program:

`./myprogram.exe(myargument)`

But it obviously doesn't work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
program arg1 arg2 arg3 "arg4 containing spaces"
```